# How much is the retail version of league of legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

There has been for some time now a retail version of league of legends, how much is it and what do i gain from buying it rather than getting the free versions off the league of legends website?

Comment: I believe Daniel is referring to the [League of Legends Collector's Pack](http://www.amazon.com/League-Legends-Pc/dp/B002HOIPCW)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there was a £30 version that gives 24 heroes, cant seem to find it now tho.

Answer (score -1):

:) You can find it in stores like Bestbuy or Walmart (If you're in the US) For $20 usually. I found it once for $10, though that offer seems to be expired [otherwise I would link it to you]. Good luck!

Silver Kayle FTW. ;)